# Superagent is causing localhost to not connect

Tags: reactjs, npm, superagent

Every time I use **npm install superagent** my localhost no longer works. Instead, the terminal asks if I want to run the app on another port ("Would you like to run the app on another port instead? (Y/n)"). No matter my response, the localhost will not run or it will not connect to the server. Is there a way to fix this? Or how do I uninstall superagent?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/superagent this package has been deprecated

Comment: Also, just installing a package doesn't usually do anything. You are doing something wrong with your terminal. I guess that your have 2 servers running at once